# Linking two UserControls with DependencyProperties (Grafical Editor)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependencies, gantt-chart

I'm trying to implement dependencies between UserControls (orange) in my application. They should be able to start/stop together or start/stop from/to a pre-definied time/position.

I have two problems:

1. Right now I've programmed a workaround to fill the white gaps between the orange positioning controls. I'm able to fill the gaps with delay controls but that's not ideal.

My first question is: How would you go about fixing the problem? I'm fairly new to MVVM and C#/WPF (student) but I've got the basics down for DependencyProperties, Events, INotifyPropertyChanged, etc. Is there a library for something like this? I guess I'll have to programm some sort of system of coordinates to freely drag&drop my usercontrols and still know the horizontal position. Is there an easier way?

2. problem:

My application should be able to connect two orange UserControls to start/stop different positioning commands with eachother (blue lines) or let the UserControls start/stop from an absolut position/time. If I shift a UserControl horizontally the connected UserControls should follow in their "axis lane". Is this achievable? How would I go about programming this? I suppose over DependencyProperties, Events and bindings in the View. Is there something that I can use that already exists? I was inspired by simple Gantt-diagrams where you can also "connect" different tasks. How would you go about programming something like this? Any input helps.

Thank you in advance! I hope I'm asking this question in the right forum, Stackoverflow has already helped me a lot.

Here is a Visio drawing of what I want to achieve:

[image: https://imgur.com/kxdFZ4U]
This is my current solution:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/rSaABzL.png]

Comment: I recommend that you split up your problem into individual little problems and ask them separately. It's also unclear to me what you mean by "dependencies between UserControls" or "start/stop" or "positioning commands" or other terminology that you use. You may get more answers if you're crystal clear on what you mean by these.

Comment: **Dependency property** has a very specific meaning in connection with WPF and I don't think it is what you are looking for. It sounds to me as if you need some data structure to couple items in your **model**. Making a link between UI elements (e.g. the UserControls) doesn't feel right to me.